# How to check if HTML sessionStorage is not empty?

Tags: javascript, html

G'day guys,

I'm trying to figure out the best way to check for empty `storageSession` in HTML5.

I noticed that some browser returns null and some return just empty space if you clear or did not set any values to the `sessionStorage`.

I've tried the following

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('value1') == "null" && sessionStorage.getItem('value2') == "null") {
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone got a better way to check if a `sessionStorage` is empty?

Appreciate your help on this and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That should work; the problem is that you have **null** in quotes.

Also, `sessionStorage.length` will give you the number of values stored.

Comment: Hi Herohtar, thank you for pointing out the error to me. Really appreciate it. As for the case of some browser returning null and some returning empty space, should we create 2 condition statement? One for null and one for empty space?

Comment: If you need to check for both, that's what you will have to do. Just out of curiosity, which browser returns empty space? getItem() should always return null if the value is not set. Also, see my addition to my answer for another possible test.

Comment: Hi Herohtar, if you do a document.write(sessionStorage.getItem('value1')); most browser will render it as null if its empty. However, it's a different story for text inputs. IE will include the word null as value in the text box.

Answer (score 6):

But this is how you check for "empty" session storage

```
   if (sessionStorage.length == 0) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to check if there is item is session storage called "name"

```
if (sessionStorage['name']) {
    console.log("There is 'name' in session storage ")
}
```

Comment: Using typeof sessionStorage['name'] === 'undefined' works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
    if($window.sessionStorage.value === undefined) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

i checked this way

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       if (window.sessionStorage) {
           if (sessionStorage.getItem("x-mas") === null) {
               if (getCountryCode() == 'de') {
                   $('#xmasModal').modal();
                   sessionStorage.setItem("x-mas", "1")
               }
           }
       }
   });

   function getCountryCode() {
       var url = window.location.pathname;
       var segments = url.split('/');
       var countrycode = segments[1];
       return countrycode;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case like this, I use:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('value1').length == 0) {}
```

Comment: I think you can't use `.length` on `null`