# Check if the Session exists with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, session

I want to display a div if the sessions with particular name exists or not using Javascript. I am not sure if Java Script allows you to do that.
The session is created from Django Python.

But if there's a way then please provide me a snippet of code to check a session's existence.

Comment: Are you talking about php session ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if HTML sessionStorage is not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704735/how-to-check-if-html-sessionstorage-is-not-empty)

Comment: what sessions? Also, SO is not for asking people to provide you with code, you are expected to put in the work. If you ask a [good, detailed question](/help/how-to-ask), we can help answer it, but if you don't, your question will either get closed or just get downvoted and passed over.

Comment: I am creating sessions from Django (Python) that I want to check on front end.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am looking for just a snippet for find session. I am not asking for complete code.

Comment: @ShreyanshLodha then you should use google, not Stackoverflow. If you want SO help, please be more specific about your technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this using javascript

```
var var_name = '<%= session.getAttribute("userName") %>';
```

Comment: It just gives me the same output. I replaced 'userName' with the session name that I have set. But it gives me `<%= session.getAttribute("<key>") %>`  as output. If i try to print it.