# Issue with Saving and Reloading a Value Locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

So in one of my projects, I am attempting to add the functionality of saving track elements from the Spotify API to the session, then pulling them again. I inserted a console log to find out that even when the element from the session storage is undefined, it still enters the if block in the `checkPlaylistName()` method. The console log in the render statement is run twice, the first time, it passes an empty array, which is what I want when no elements are passed, the second time, it passes undefined for some reason. That's what causes an error in a different component, saying it is passed undefined. If you need the whole repo, you can find it [here](https://github.com/BeauRussell/Codecademy-Jammming). Otherwise, this is the code causing the issues:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';
import Spotify from '../../util/Spotify.js';


class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   searchResults: [],
   playlistName: 'New Playlist',
   playlistTracks: [],
   term: ''
  }
  this.addTrack = this.addTrack.bind(this);
  this.removeTrack = this.removeTrack.bind(this);
  this.updatePlaylistName = this.updatePlaylistName.bind(this);
  this.savePlaylist = this.savePlaylist.bind(this);
  this.search = this.search.bind(this);
 }

 addTrack(track) {
  const addingTrack = (track) => this.setState({playlistTracks: [...this.state.playlistTracks, track]});
  addingTrack(track);
  this.removeTrack(track, false);
  sessionStorage.setItem("playlistTracks", this.state.playlistTracks);
 }

 removeTrack(track, removePlaylist) {
  if(removePlaylist) {
   const ids = this.collectIds(true);
   let trackIndex = -1;
   for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (ids[i] === track.id) {
     trackIndex = i;
    }
   }
   if (trackIndex !== -1) {
    const newPlaylist = this.state.playlistTracks;
    newPlaylist.splice(trackIndex, 1);
    this.setState({playlistTracks: newPlaylist});
    this.search(this.state.term);
   }
  } else {
   const ids = this.collectIds(false);
   let trackIndex = -1;
   for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (ids[i] === track.id) {
     trackIndex = i;
    }
   }
   if (trackIndex !== -1) {
    const newResults = this.state.searchResults;
    newResults.splice(trackIndex, 1);
    this.setState({searchResults: newResults});
   }
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem("playlistTracks", this.state.playlistTracks);
 }

 collectIds(removePlaylist) {
  let ids = [];
  if(removePlaylist) {
   this.state.playlistTracks.map(track => ids.push(track.id));
  } else {
   this.state.searchResults.map(track => ids.push(track.id));
  }
  return ids;
 }

 updatePlaylistName(name) {
  this.setState({playlistName: name});
  sessionStorage.setItem("playlistName", name);
 }

 savePlaylist() {
  let trackURIs = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.state.playlistTracks.length; i++) {
   trackURIs.push(this.state.playlistTracks[i].uri);
  }
  Spotify.savePlaylist(this.state.playlistName, trackURIs);
  this.setState({playlistName: 'New Playlist', playlistTracks: []});
  sessionStorage.removeItem("playlistTracks");
  sessionStorage.removeItem("playlistName");
 }

 async search(term) {
  const results = await Spotify.search(term);
  this.setState({searchResults: results});
  const resultIds = this.collectIds(false);
  const playlistIds = this.collectIds(true);
  let indexes = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < resultIds.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0; j < playlistIds.length; j++) {
    if (resultIds[i] === playlistIds[j]) {
     indexes.push(i);
    }
   }
  }
  if(indexes.length > 0) {
   for (let k = 0; k < indexes.length; k++) {
    results.splice(indexes[k], 1);
   }
  }
  this.setState({searchResults: results});
  this.setState({term: term});
 }

 checkTracks() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("playlistTracks") !== undefined) {
   const tracks = sessionStorage.getItem("playlistTracks");
   this.setState({playlistTracks: tracks});
  }
  return this.state.playlistTracks;
 }

 checkPlaylistName() {
  const savedName = sessionStorage.getItem("playlistName");
  if (savedName !== null || savedName !== undefined) {
   this.setState({playlistName: savedName});
   console.log("hi");
  }
  return this.state.playlistName;
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div id="root">
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
        <div className="App-playlist">
           <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} onAdd={this.addTrack} onRemove={this.removeTrack} />
           {console.log(this.checkTracks())}
           <Playlist 
            playlistName={this.checkPlaylistName()}
            playlistTracks={this.checkTracks()}
            onRemove={this.removeTrack}
            onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
            onSave={this.savePlaylist}
           />
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: [`getItem()` returns `null` if no item exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if HTML sessionStorage is not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704735/how-to-check-if-html-sessionstorage-is-not-empty)

Comment: Switching it from undefined to null changes nothing

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with code you're not showing.

Comment: I added the entire component to see if something else is wrong with it. There shouldn't be an issue with any others, since this is the only one that I changed

Comment: One of the problem might be you are setting state in checkTracks which is called from render, every setState triggers re-render therefore if sessionStorage has playlistTracks you get into infinite cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState function is asynchronous (https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b), therefore you are returning old state in checkTracks method.

Solution:
Don't setState in your checkTracks method, make it:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("playlistTracks") !== undefined) {
    return sessionStorage.getItem("playlistTracks");
}
return [];
```

And use this method in constructor to define state.

Also in your way you are setting state (via checkTracks method) in render function which causes an infinite loop.